# A list of layer names that you want to be turned off when Layers name are in Right to Left Such as persian

Tags: python-2.7, arcpy, unicode

[image][image][image]When I ran this code I got "UnicodeWarning: Unicode equal comparison failed to convert both arguments to Unicode - interpreting them as being unequal" error I don't know why I tried many way but I could not success where is my mistake?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
#A list of layer names that you want to be turned off.
import arcpy
names =["باران سنجی","برف سنجی","هیدرومتری"]
arcpy.env.workspace = "E:\GIS\Data_Base_93_07_10\Data_Base.gdb"
mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"E:\GIS\WebGIS_Abniro_Final.mxd")
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
layers = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd)
for layer in layers:
    if layer.name in names:
        layer.visible=False
        print layer.visible
arcpy.RefreshTOC()
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Comment: I would try `print layer.name` as the first line after your `for` line to see if it prints something that looks like the first of the three names in your list.

Comment: In your picture you have highlighted a layer group.  I don't think that will be the cause but perhaps copy the layers with and without that grouping into a test MXD to see if your code runs in either case.

Comment: I tried when Layres were ungroup but I got same error message

Comment: Did layer.name print out sensible values?

Comment: unfortunately, It didn't